# dash.js latest version (2.2.0) not working for live streaming

Tags: video, ionic-framework, dash.js

I'm developing an on demand video app for Ionic using Dash.js.
I was using version 1.x (can't remember x) and it worked for both live and not live streaming but i had to upgrade to the latest version (2.2.0) to make it compatible with some other libraries i'm using. The problem is that with this new version, live streaming isn't working anymore.

This is what i had for the previous version:

```
video = document.getElementById('video-player');
context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
player = new MediaPlayer(context);
player.startup();
player.attachView(video);
player.setAutoPlay(false);
widevineLicenseServerUrl = license;
manifestUrl = manifest;
customDataWv = {
  "Conax-Custom-Data": cxWidevine.getCxCustomDataForWidevine(token)
};
protectionData = {
  "com.widevine.alpha": new MediaPlayer.vo.protection.ProtectionData(widevineLicenseServerUrl, customDataWv)
};
player.attachSource(manifestUrl, null, protectionData);
```

And for the latest version:

```
video = document.getElementById('video-player');
player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
player.initialize(video, null, false);
manifestUrl = $scope.play.link;
customDataWv = {
  "Conax-Custom-Data": cxWidevine.getCxCustomDataForWidevine(token)
};
protectionData = {
  "com.widevine.alpha": {
      serverURL: widevineLicenseServerUrl,
      httpRequestHeaders: customDataWv,
      clearkeys: null
   }
};
player.setProtectionData(protectionData);
player.attachSource(manifestUrl);
```

So as i said, the problem is that i can't find a way to reproduce live content, with the older version i didn't have to differentiate between live and non-live but with the new version the same code doesn't work for both cases.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion/advice!

Comment: Resolved: https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/issues/1601#issuecomment-248053948